# PHP - isse array optimization

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, isset

From an optimisation and best practice stand-point should I check that an array key isset before setting it.

I'm happy to overwrite the value - so either would suit my purpose.

In this simple example I know what values my array should have and I have no problem overwriting a key value.

```
    $array = array(
        'A' => 'B'
    );

    $key = 'A';
    $value = 'B';

    //...
```

Option 1.

```
    //...

    if(!isset($array[$key])) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Option 2.

```
    //...

    $array[$key] = $value;
```

Is there more overhead calling *isset*, or setting a value in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know a whole lot of specifics on times, but if there is a difference I highly doubt it would be noticeable. If we look at this from just a logic standpoint the two compare:

1)Does the value exist?
2a)If yes, override.
2b)If no, skip.

1)Override value.

The argument could be made either way, since the resources are being used to check and then override. So in fact, you are doing the same step as the second option but adding in a if statement. By that logic, just overriding HAS to be faster. Make sense?

With our second option, all we do is override. With the first, we check AND override. So if you are certain that you will mostly be overriding, then the second option is probably best. If you think the values will change consistently, then go for the if statement.

You will have to get in some deep deep research to find the EXACT time difference.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much but I wasn't sure. Looking at another persons code and trying to work out why they did it the first way.